# Import sales data into Quickbooks via .IIF files

Tags: java, quickbooks, iif

I'm trying to import Sales into Quickbooks 2013 with an IIF file.

Background:
I'm developing an export engine for those IIF files for Quickbooks and now I'm trying to import sales datas into it.

The message from Quickbooks is following:

> The Tax field cannot be left blank, even for non- taxable customers
>   and sales which have to no taxable items, so non-taxable sales will be
>   correct for this district.

Examples of the receipts I try to import are:

```
TRNS    1001148    CASH SALE    08/27/2014    Service            "19,95"    1001148        Y    Y             
SPL        CASH SALE    08/27/2014    Spirituosen            "-16,76"        "Aalborg Jubiläums Akvavit 0.70l Fl"    -1    "19,95"    5700359304907    Y     
SPL        CASH SALE    0    0            "-3,19"        "Voller Satz"    -1    "-3,19"    Sales Tax    N     
ENDTRNS
TRNS    1001147    CASH SALE    08/27/2014    Service            "39,90"    1001147        Y    Y             
SPL        CASH SALE    08/27/2014    Spirituosen            "-16,76"        "Aalborg Jubiläums Akvavit 0.70l Fl"    -1    "19,95"    5700359304907    Y     
SPL        CASH SALE    08/27/2014    Spirituosen            "-16,76"        "Aalborg Jubiläums Akvavit 0.70l Fl"    -1    "19,95"    5700359304907    Y     
SPL        CASH SALE    0    0            "-6,38"        "Voller Satz"    -1    "-6,38"    Sales Tax    N     
ENDTRNS
```

Actually I'm exporting these files manualy.
Is there a way or a library to export IIF files preferably in Java?

Answer (score 2):

The IIF format has been deprecated for about 10 years now. You should not be using it. It has many known limitations, and is known to bypass validation routines and corrupt QuickBooks company files.

Instead, you should be using qbXML and/or the QuickBooks SDK.

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0250_qb